# C# Drawing oriented graph

Tags: c#, tree, drawing

Is there a well documented way to draw an oriented graph or tree in the C# language, without using external libraries?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able use the System.Drawing namespace to draw and then just do the math and computational stuff yourself.

Comment: Just because you mentioned it: What are common algorithms for positioning graph nodes and edges with less intersections as possible? Can you provide any names I could look up? I used a spring attraction/distraction method years ago...

Comment: Yes, spring layout is one common technique; another is known as 'Sugiyama'.  GraphViz supports a couple of different techniques.  There is no single algorithm that always does well.  See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347748/planar-graph-layouts

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You'll use the System.Drawing namespace (more info [here](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/05/20/drawing.html)).  You'll want to create a virtual canvas large enough to handle your widest and tallest extents.  These can be calculated by figuring the number of leaves in your tree (it is a bit more difficult with a graph) and then adding a spacing factor, etc.

It isn't a *hard* problem but it is tedious.  It took me about a day several years ago.  Sorry but I abandoned the interface as too clumsy and didn't keep the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the [`System.Drawing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing?view=netframework-4.7.2) namespace, which contains drawing functions/classes.

Basically to draw, you do this:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
Image img = bmp;
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
```

Then use `g.FillRectangle` , `g.DrawLine`, `g.DrawString` etc.

Remember that `0,0` is on top left though :)