# Drawing a graph on the plane

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, planar-graph

I've got a hometask :

To make the visualizer of *planar graph* embedding (or laying I don't know a correct word for this process).

*Planar graph* is isomorphic to *plane graph*, and a *plane graph* is a graph drawn on the plane without intersections of its edges.

I need an algorithm to do this, there is one article in Russian, the algorithm named "Gamma algorithm" is descrbed there, but I want to find some more information, and I couldn't even find anything about "Gamma algorithm" (in English, it seems like it has another name), nor about other algorithm in English.

Could anyone suggest the names of the algorithms and links to their descriptions?

*p.s. sorry if my English is bad :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've stumbled across the algorithm i've been searching for — according to http://www.cs.brown.edu/~rt/gdhandbook/chapters/planarity.pdf it is Auslander and Parter ,or Goldstein cycle-based algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You have some answers on [Planar Graph Layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347748/planar-graph-layouts)