# Draw Network in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph

I need to draw a network (not a neural network) with 5 nodes and 20 directed edges (an edge connecting each 2 nodes), and I need to be able to control the thickness of each edge. Is there a toolbox in Matlab offering this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804468/matlab-drawing-network-of-nodes-in-circular-formation-with-links-between-nodes/5806123#5806123

Comment: @Pansy: do you have specific locations for the nodes, or do you want automatic layout?

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution in R 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521381/draw-network-in-r-control-edge-thickness-plus-non-overlapping-edges/7528002#7528002

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Bioinformatics Toolbox will allow you to do this with the [biograph](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/biograph.html) command.