# igraph package in r: edge labels are overlapping

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I am working with the igraph package in R to visualise network flows.

```
library(igraph)

# Example Data:
b <- c("countryA", "countryB", "countryC", "countryA", "countryC", "countryA")
c <- c("countryB", "countryC", "countryA", "countryB", "countryA", "countryB")
d<- c(100, 200, 200, 300, 400, 200)
e <- c(5,12,10,24,25,12)
mydata <- data.frame(b,c,d,e)
colnames(mydata) <- c("exporteur", "partner", "tradeflow", "price")

# Plot in igraph
mydata.igraph <- graph.data.frame(mydata)
E(mydata.igraph)$label <- mydata[,3]
plot(mydata.igraph)
```

As you can see, my edge labels (labels of the arrows) are overlapping. How to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `vertex.label.dist` is possible but it [seems not yet for edges](https://bugs.launchpad.net/igraph/+bug/530802)

Comment: You can't easily right now, you cannot customize placement of edge labels in R igraph. Take a look at the `sna` package, maybe that supports it, although I haven't checked, so I am not sure. If you want to plot diagrams, you can also look at the `diagram` package. To do it with igraph, you'll need to plot the labels as an additional step, with the `text()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code to do it. It uses the edgelist instead of the igraph, but it is a cooler looking graph.

```
    library(qgraph)
    qgraph(mydata,edge.labels=T)
```

Check out this post for a more detail

[Draw Network in R (control edge thickness plus non-overlapping edges)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521381/draw-network-in-r-control-edge-thickness-plus-non-overlapping-edges)

And this help page for using qgraph:
http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM/R_rdfile?f=qgraph/man/qgraph.Rd&d=R_CC