# R: Creating Markov Chains from Data Frames

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, data-visualization, markov-chains

I am working with the R programming language.

I thought of the following "game":

- There are two coins : Coin 1 and Coin 2
- The player picks a random coin (i.e. 0.5 probability of picking either Coin 1 or Coin 2)
- Coin 1 has a 0.5 probability of landing on Heads and a 0.5 probability of landing on Tails
- Coin 2 has a 0.3 probability of landing on Heads and a 0.7 probability of landing on Tails
- If Coin 1 is Heads, the player gets a score of 1 else 0
- If coin 2 is Heads, the player gets a score of 2 else -1
- The player repeats this 3 times and records his final score
- Note: The player starts the game with score = 0

I want to make a "Markov Chain" (e.g. https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/01/getting-started-with-markov-chains/ , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain, [Markov Chains and decimal points in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49762513/markov-chains-and-decimal-points-in-r)) for this game that shows the probability of what score the player can have conditional on the current turn and current score - based on "simulated data" from this game.

The "states" of the Markov Chain are the different scores that a player can have at any point in the game, and the "edges" are the probability of being in any of these "states" conditional on the current "state".

Although we have the exact probabilities in this game - I would specifically like to calculate the transition probabilities based on some simulated data (e.g. 100 iterations) from this game.

I wrote a simulation that plays this game 100 times:

```
library(dplyr)

results <- list()

 for (i in 1:100) {

iteration = i

coin_turn_1_i = sample(sample(c(1,2)), size =1, replace = T, prob= c(0.5,0.5))

score_turn_1_i = ifelse(coin_turn_1_i == 1, sample(sample(c(1,0)), size =1, replace = T, prob= c(0.5,0.5)), sample(sample(c(2,-1)), size =1, replace = T, prob= c(0.3,0.7)) )

coin_turn_2_i = sample(sample(c(1,2)), size =1, replace = T, prob= c(0.5,0.5))

score_turn_2_i = ifelse(coin_turn_2_i == 1, sample(sample(c(1,0)), size =1, replace = T, prob= c(0.5,0.5)), sample(sample(c(2,-1)), size =1, replace = T, prob= c(0.3,0.7)) )

cum_score_2_i = score_turn_2_i + score_turn_1_i

coin_turn_3_i = sample(sample(c(1,2)), size =1, replace = T, prob= c(0.5,0.5))

score_turn_3_i = ifelse(coin_turn_3_i == 1, sample(sample(c(1,0)), size =1, replace = T, prob= c(0.5,0.5)), sample(sample(c(2,-1)), size =1, replace = T, prob= c(0.3,0.7)) )

total_score_i = score_turn_3_i + cum_score_2_i


my_data_i = data.frame(iteration, coin_turn_1_i, score_turn_1_i, coin_turn_2_i, score_turn_2_i, cum_score_2_i, coin_turn_3_i, score_turn_3_i, total_score_i )

results[[i]] <- my_data_i

}

results_df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind.data.frame, results))
```

I tried to (manually) extract the "transition probabilities" between "turn 1 and turn 2" and "turn 2 and turn 3":

```
#turn 1 and turn 2

turn_1_and_turn_2 =  data.frame(results_df %>% group_by(score_turn_1_i, cum_score_2_i) %>% summarise(count = n()))

results_df %>% group_by(score_turn_1_i) %>% summarise(count = n())
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  score_turn_1_i count
           <dbl> <int>
1             -1    25
2              0    22
3              1    28
4              2    25

# transition probabilities 
turn_1_and_turn_2$prob = ifelse(turn_1_and_turn_2$score_turn_1_i == -1, turn_1_and_turn_2$count/25, ifelse(turn_1_and_turn_2$score_turn_1_i == 0, turn_1_and_turn_2$count/22, ifelse(turn_1_and_turn_2$score_turn_1_i == 1, turn_1_and_turn_2$count/28, turn_1_and_turn_2$count/25)))

# turn 2 and turn 3


turn_2_and_turn_3 =  data.frame(results_df %>% group_by( cum_score_2_i, total_score_i) %>% summarise(count = n()))

results_df %>% group_by(cum_score_2_i) %>% summarise(count = n())

# A tibble: 7 x 2
  cum_score_2_i count
          <dbl> <int>
1            -2     5
2            -1    13
3             0    22
4             1    20
5             2    21
6             3    13
7             4     6

turn_2_and_turn_3$prob = ifelse(turn_2_and_turn_3$cum_score_2_i == -2, turn_2_and_turn_3$count/5, ifelse(turn_2_and_turn_3$cum_score_2_i == -1, turn_2_and_turn_3$count/13, ifelse(turn_2_and_turn_3$cum_score_2_i == 0, turn_2_and_turn_3$count/22, ifelse(turn_2_and_turn_3$cum_score_2_i == 1, turn_2_and_turn_3$count/20, ifelse(turn_2_and_turn_3$cum_score_2_i == 2, turn_2_and_turn_3$count/21, ifelse(turn_2_and_turn_3$cum_score_2_i == 3, turn_2_and_turn_3$count/13, turn_2_and_turn_3$count/6))))))
```

**My Question:** But from here, I do not know how to take "turn_1_and_turn_2$prob" and "turn_2_and_turn_3$prob" and convert them into a transition matrix - and then convert them into a "Markov Chain" :

[image]

Of course - I could manually enter the all the above probabilities into a matrix object:

```
#for a n-state transition matrix
transition_matrix = matrix(1:n^2, nrow = n, ncol = n)
```

But can someone please show me how to make this kind of Markov Chain directly from "results_df"? Is there a general method that can be used for "results_df" if the player flips the coin as much as he wants (e.g. 4 times)?

Thanks!

**Note:** In this game I have created, it seems that the game can end in 9 possible states - so I think this means that the transition matrix would be 9x9?

```
turn_2_and_turn_3 %>% group_by(total_score_i) %>% summarise(count = n())
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  total_score_i count
          <dbl> <int>
1            -3     1
2            -2     2
3            -1     3
4             0     3
5             1     4
6             2     4
7             3     4
8             4     3
9             5     2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can try `igraph` when you are constructing the transision matrix using directed graph, e.g.,

```
library(igraph)

t1_t2 <- results_df %>%
  group_by(from = score_turn_1_i, to = cum_score_2_i) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), .groups = "drop")

t2_t3 <- results_df %>%
  group_by(from = cum_score_2_i, to = total_score_i) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), .groups = "drop")

g <- rbind(
  t1_t2, t2_t3
) %>%
  group_by(from, to) %>%
  summarise(freq = sum(count), .groups = "drop") %>%
  group_by(from) %>%
  mutate(freq = round(proportions(freq), 3)) %>%
  graph_from_data_frame()
```

where `g` is an `igraph` object, and you will obtain the transition matrix using `get.adjacency`

```
> g %>% get.adjacency(attr = "freq")
9 x 9 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
      -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4    -3     5
-2 0.154 0.231 0.154 .     .     .     .     0.462 .
-1 0.340 0.260 0.220 0.180 .     .     .     .     .
0  .     0.321 0.214 0.250 0.214 .     .     .     .
1  .     .     0.303 0.121 0.273 0.303 .     .     .
2  .     .     .     0.200 0.257 0.314 0.229 .     .
3  .     .     .     .     0.500 0.250 0.125 .     0.125
4  .     .     .     .     .     0.200 0.200 .     0.600
-3 .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
5  .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
```

and plot the Markov chain like below

```
g %>% plot(edge.label = E(.)$freq, layout = layout_as_star)
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: If the simulated data had more coin flips - I think I should be able to manually adapt the code you have provided to work for a game with 4 coin flips?

Comment: On a unrelated note: can you please take a look at this question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71405546/r-contour-plots-for-functions thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob yes, I think you can apply the code in a similar way when with 4 coin flips