# R: Contour Plots for Functions

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language.

I am trying to make a Contour Plot for the following function:

```
library(plotly)


  my_function <- function(x,y) {
    
    final_value = x^2 + y^2
    }


input_1 <- seq(-1.5, 1.5,0.1)
input_2 <- seq(-1.5, 1.5,0.1)


z <- outer(input_1, input_2, my_function)

plot_ly(x = input_1, y = input_2, z = z) %>% add_surface()
```

[image]

I am trying to follow the instructions from this link over here: https://r-charts.com/correlation/contour-plot-ggplot2/. In this link, it shows how to make a contour plot for a data frame containing values for two different variables. In my case, it looks like I already have a matrix called "z". I tried to use the code from the website:

```
# install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

# Data
set.seed(1)

z = data.frame(z)

ggplot(z, aes(x = input_1, y = input_2)) +
  geom_density_2d_filled()
```

[image]

**Can someone please tell me if what I have done is correct? Is this how Contour Plots (Level Plots) are made for functions using ggplot2?**

The reason I am skeptical is because I tried to repeat this process for a completely different function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rastrigin_function) and got a very similar result:

```
 my_function <- function(x1, x2) {
    
    final_value = 20 + x1^2 + x2^2 - 10*(cos(2*pi*x1) + cos(2*pi*x2))
    }


x1 <- seq(-5, 5,0.1)
x2 <- seq(-5, 5,0.1)


z <- data.frame(outer(x1, x2, my_function))


ggplot(z, aes(x = x1, y = x2)) +
  geom_density_2d_filled()
```

[image]

```
z <- outer(x1, x2, my_function)

plot_ly(x = x1, y = x2, z = z) %>% add_surface()
```

[image]

**I don't think this is correct - both functions look entirely different and I doubt they would have the same contour plots. This makes me skeptical and think that I am doing something wrong.**

Thanks!

**Note:** Ideally, the contour plot of the second function should look something like this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Rastrigin-smooth-contour.svg

Comment: The object `z` doesn't have columns called `input_1` and `input_2`, so your ggplot call is taking these two vectors from the global environment. They are numerically the same vector, so you just have a bunch of points along the line y = x. The `geom_density_2d` is creating a 2d density plot of these points, where the peak is along the line y = x, and fades away according to a normal kernel. You probably need to `reshape2::melt` your matrix into an x, y, z data frame and use `geom_contour_filled`

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to do this ... if you have time, can you please show me how to do this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try this

```
expand.grid(X1 = x1, X2 = x2) %>%
  mutate(Z = my_function(X1, X2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(X1, X2, z = Z)) +
  geom_contour() +
  geom_contour_filled()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect!